# how to secure flutter plugin/package ? allow Methods to be used but restrict the access to implementation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I have encryption/decryption code which has "secret code" and "IV" which i don't want the the other developers to know, if i create a flutter package how can i achieve this so that developers should use the methods encrypt/decrypt but should not see the actual implementation especially "secret key" and "IV". any suggestions will help thanks you

Answer (score 0):

**convert your code server relate**
build small site with some route for your function
such that they make request and retrieve the answer

[example with node](https://github.com/SoftCareTech/NumberToWords)

Comment: This did not help. i want the solution for flutter and for flutter package

Comment: Okay...  if it it java i would ask to build the jar file... but still on read the jar file to simple code. Let use mock function that shows result is okay.. then u will recive last solution and build apk. but remember code in apk can read by any